# API support for Bluemix Availability Monitoring service

Tags: ibm-cloud, availability-monitoring

I am looking for API support for Bluemix Availability Monitoring service to report availability across all components of the service. Currently I need to individually select every application to see the availability. The availability reporting is for SLA.

I could not find any reference to APIs. Any pointers would help greatly. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that this YouTube video should help you to get this information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c7_PKng_gc

Comment: Hi Bill, the video is about configuring Availability Monitoring service for API and web page testing. Lets assume I have 25 apps I want to monitor for uptime. There is no single dashboard to view that. If I can query availability and uptime via service APIs I can build my custom dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Availability Monitoring doesn't currently expose any APIs, but it is in the roadmap to do so in the future.  For now, you can get a "global" view by choosing 1 app (even a stopped dummy app), and put all your tests there.  You do not need to create the tests in the actual app that is monitored.  If using the Lite/Free plan, you may run into test point limits using this approach.

Comment: Thanks. As you rightly said, this is what I am doing right now. Would be glad to know when API support will be available.